# Single Table / Multiple tables Inheritance in JPA / Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, jakarta-ee

I'am creating a management system , I have many type of USERS : 

- "Client" doing orders / view and modify his orders 

- "Manager" manage orders 

- "Accountant" ...

So what is the best choice , make them in seperate classes (How to make the relations ?)

Or make a single class "User" with a column "type_user",For example  "Manager" is related to other classes ("Order" for example ) so my question is in the "Order" table should I put a relation (key) with "User" or "Manager"?? (I don't have an ID in Manager )

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

They are role. Create User and Role Table. Then map user to Specific role using user-Role-Map.

Comment: I hope, this will help you.

Comment: Can you answer , I sent you an email